# Terraform EMR Studio error: The service role does not have permission to access the <cluster name>

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-emr

trying to attach a emr studio and workspace to a emr cluster via terraform. But get an error saying:

```
 Error: creating EMR Studio: InvalidRequestException: The service role does not have permission to access the dev-emr. Review the policies for the service role and the S3 bucket policy to ensure that the permission is granted. (Service: AWSEditors; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: 9c904871-78e2-4893-88a4-f6410b3da4b0; Proxy: null)
│ {
│   RespMetadata: {
│     StatusCode: 400,
│     RequestID: "9d6bd37a-c61f-4ad2-87e8-8eb9c4cb0f27"
│   },
│   Message_: "The service role does not have permission to access the dev-emr. Review the policies for the service role and the S3 bucket policy to ensure that the permission is granted. (Service: AWSEditors; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException; Request ID: 9c904871-78e2-4893-88a4-f6410b3da4b0; Proxy: null)"
│ }
│ 
│   with aws_emr_studio.emr-studio,
│   on emr-studio.tf line 1, in resource "aws_emr_studio" "emr-studio":
│    1: resource "aws_emr_studio" "emr-studio" {
```

Studio code is:

```
resource "aws_emr_studio" "emr-studio" {
  name                        = "${local.full_name}-studio"
  auth_mode                   = "IAM"
  default_s3_location         = "s3://${var.s3_prevent_destroy == true ? aws_s3_bucket.emr[0].id : aws_s3_bucket.emr-destroy[0].id}/studio"
  engine_security_group_id    = aws_security_group.emr-studio.id
  service_role                = aws_iam_role.iam_emr_service_role.arn
  subnet_ids                  = [data.aws_subnets.intra.ids[0], data.aws_subnets.intra.ids[1], data.aws_subnets.intra.ids[2]]
  #user_role                   = aws_iam_role.iam_studio_user_role.arn
  vpc_id                      = data.aws_vpc.this.id
  workspace_security_group_id = aws_security_group.emr-studio.id
}
```

My iam role has

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "studio_service_role" {
  name = "${local.full_name}-studio-service-role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Principal" : {
          "Service" : "elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action" : "sts:AssumeRole",
    }]
  })
}
```

and the following policy attached:

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "studio_service_role" {
  name        = "${local.full_name}-studio-service-policy"
  description = "copy of EMR_Notebooks_DefaultRole policy with extras"
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
       {
      "Sid": "AllowEMRReadOnlyActions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "elasticmapreduce:ListInstances",
        "elasticmapreduce:DescribeCluster",
        "elasticmapreduce:ListSteps"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowEC2ENIActionsWithEMRTags",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission",
        "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*"
      ],
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowEC2ENIAttributeAction",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowEC2SecurityGroupActionsWithEMRTags",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
        "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
        "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
        "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
        "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterfacePermission"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowDefaultEC2SecurityGroupsCreationWithEMRTags",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:RequestTag/for-use-with-amazon-emr-managed-policies": "true"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowDefaultEC2SecurityGroupsCreationInVPCWithEMRTags",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:vpc/*"
      ],
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowAddingEMRTagsDuringDefaultSecurityGroupCreation",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowEC2ENICreationWithEMRTags",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*"
      ],
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowEC2ENICreationInSubnetAndSecurityGroupWithEMRTags",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*"
      ],
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowAddingTagsDuringEC2ENICreation",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowEC2ReadOnlyActions",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
        "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
        "ec2:DescribeTags",
        "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
        "ec2:DescribeVpcs"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowSecretsManagerReadOnlyActionsWithEMRTags",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:*:*:secret:*",
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowWorkspaceCollaboration",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:GetUser",
        "iam:GetRole",
        "iam:ListUsers",
        "iam:ListRoles",
        "sso:GetManagedApplicationInstance",
        "sso-directory:SearchUsers"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
      },
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "Resource" : "*"
      },
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : "s3:*",
        "Resource" : "*"
      },
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : [
          "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
          "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
          "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup",
          "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
          "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
          "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
          "ec2:CreateNetworkInterfacePermission",
          "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
          "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterfacePermission",
          "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
          "ec2:ModifyNetworkInterfaceAttribute",
          "ec2:DescribeTags",
          "ec2:DescribeInstances",
          "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
          "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
          "elasticmapreduce:ListInstances",
          "elasticmapreduce:DescribeCluster",
          "elasticmapreduce:ListSteps"
        ],
        "Resource" : "*"
      },
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Action" : "ec2:CreateTags",
        "Resource" : "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

this is basically a copy and paste of all resource options from the following docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-studio-service-role.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-service-role.html

Any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `dev-emr` coming from?

Comment: thats the name of the EMR cluster that i want it to connect to. creating the studio im not referencing it (or didnt think i was) as im saying connect to all EMR Clusters in the IAM Role.

Comment: Which part of the policy allows access to all EMR clusters?

Comment: i didn't specific conditions with the sts:assumerole for elastic and all the other permissions which i copied from the default_notebook didnt have conditions in. theres a Sid called: AllowEMRReadOnlyActions which i presumed would enough. (to be honest i dont get why a notebook would need 3/4 of whats in there.. but cant find anything in the docs to support that! so trying it for now

Comment: I assume the S3 bucket is not encrypted with `SSE-KMS`, as the policy doesn't contain such permissions, right?

Answer (score 0):

The document has an important session, which mentions:

> To use the example policy, you must tag the following resources with the key "for-use-with-amazon-emr-managed-policies" and value "true".
>
> - Your Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) for EMR Studio.
> - Each subnet that you want to use with the Studio.
> - Any custom EMR Studio security groups. You must tag any security groups that you created during the EMR Studio preview period if you want to continue to use them.
> - Secrets maintained in AWS Secrets Manager that Studio users use to link Git repositories to a Workspace.

Or if you prefer, remove those conditions in your IAM policies.

Comment: Hey, thanks yes i found that and removed all the conditional resources to the IAM. (i will update the questions code example